# Receiving undefined when retrieving value from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Where is my call wrong? The first console.log leads to the role object and the second console.log leads to undefined. When it should be the user.

```
componentDidMount(){
    let user = fire.auth().currentUser;
    let db = fire.database();
    let roleRef = db.ref('/roles');
    roleRef.orderByChild('user').equalTo(user.uid).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
        console.log(snapshot.val().user);
    })
}
```

Result:

[image]

Firebase:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code doesn't take the list into account. The easiest way to do so is with `Snapshot.forEach()`:

```
roleRef.orderByChild('user').equalTo(user.uid).once('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshof.forEach((roleSnapshot) => {
    console.log(roleSnapshot.val())
    console.log(roleSnapshot.val().user);
  });
})
```

Comment: I see! Thank you very much.